# VSCode JSDoc type checking

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, lint

In VSCode, if I write this JS file:

```js
/** @type {number} */
let x = 10;
/** @type {string} */
let y = x;
```

nothing is underlined in red, and the tooltip over `y` simply gives `let y: string`. That is not what I want! I want VSCode to throw me an error, as it does in a TS file:

```
let x: number = 10;
let y: string = x;
```

In the file above, `y` is underlined in red and the tooltip when hovering over it gives `TS2332: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'`

How can I achieve that? Should I tweak a VSCode setting? Should I use a particular ESLint or JSHint feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a VSCode setting for that:

1. Open the settings (File > Preferences > Settings, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>)
2. Make sure the `Javascript > Implicit project config > Check JS` option has been checked

Comment: For me, it's now `JS/TS > Implicit project config > Check JS`

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to handle that, the first one is the one @nino-filiu said

> Open the settings (File > Preferences > Settings, shortcut Ctrl+,)
>
> Make sure the Javascript > Implicit project config > Check JS option has been checked

So it will be enabled by default. **This requires the rest of the team to do the same IDE config** (in case you're not working alone) and it can be escaped at file level by adding `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of a specific file.

The second one is just adding `// @ts-check` at the top of your file so this specific file will be checked by default from now on and cannot be escaped unless either you change it to `// @ts-nocheck` or you delete this line.